# How to set up cron job on CentOS

Tags: centos, cron, repeat

I don't know how to set up cron with ssh?
I opened ssh and typed "crontab -e". What do I do then? 
I want to repeat the function every minute. I have this code as "cron command to run": php -f /var/www/vhosts/nf-test-host.tk/httpdocs/admin/cron/cron.php.

I am on CentOS. What should I do, exactly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not read the centos doc? It is very simple, [CentOS doc link](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-autotasks.html)

Comment: I do agree, it's also supposed to stay on ServerFault in my opinion...

Answer (score 4):

You can try out different timing values in the crontab sandbox. It will show you a list of run times. www.dataphyx.com/cronsandbox/.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer:

http://drupal.org/node/23714

(If you are not running Drupal, that is fine, this still applies equally well to you.)

Let us know.

Comment: To provide for link rot, the relevant content should be excerpted from the linked article.

Answer (score 1):

Use command:

```
sudo yum install vixie-cron crontabs
```

or look this
http://shanerutter.co.uk/2011/11/23/centos-installing-cron-cronjobs-or-cron-daemon-crond/